# PL/SQL Pragma incorrectly violated

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

My package header code looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE INST_PKG IS
    ...
    FUNCTION Check_View (
        view_name_ IN VARCHAR2 ) RETURN BOOLEAN;
    PRAGMA restrict_references (Check_View, WNDS);
    ...
END INST_PKG;
```

And the body of the function is defined as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY INST_PKG IS

    ....

    FUNCTION View_Exist (
        view_name_ IN VARCHAR2 ) RETURN BOOLEAN
    IS
        ck_ NUMBER := 0;
        CURSOR check_view IS
            SELECT 1
            FROM   user_views uv
            WHERE  uv.view_name = upper(view_name_);
    BEGIN
        OPEN  check_view;
        FETCH check_view INTO ck_;
        IF check_view%FOUND THEN
            CLOSE check_view;
            RETURN true;
        ELSE
            CLOSE check_view;
            RETURN false;
        END IF;
    END View_Exist;

    ....

END INST_PKG;
```

I get an error message which reads as follows, when I try to compile the package body:

```
Compilation errors for PACKAGE BODY INST_PKG

Error: PLS-00452: Subprogram 'VIEW_EXIST' violates its associated pragma
Line: 684
Text: FUNCTION View_Exist (
```

Clearly, my pragma of "Write No Database State" is not violated, as there are no DML statements in the function.  Has anyone seen such behaviour before?

Of course, I could drop the Pragma reference, but that would kind of defeat the purpose.

**Worthy of note:** 
My database has been exported from an Oracle 10g instance, and has been re-imported to 12c.  (This is an upgrade test, as you might imagine).  Hence I get the above error on Oracle 12c.

I have tried to drop and re-create the package, but that doesn't seem to change things.

I have a feeling that there may be a library reference somewhere that has been imported in error, because when I drop the package, the same error comes up in another package, which contains a function of the same name.  But when I re-create the INST_PKG, the second package compiles fine, almost as though the problem in the first package is masking it from being flagged in the second.

Comment: This may help you: http://www.orafaq.com/usenet/comp.databases.oracle.server/2005/06/01/0035.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It emerges from the link you showed, that the issue is a result of a bug in USER_VIEWS (Oracle forgot to associate PRAGMA restrict_references with NO_ROOT_SW_FOR_LOCAL).
In this case you can be certain that your function doesn't violate WNDS assertion (doesn't write to the database), therefore just use TRUST option to disable assertions validation during compilation:

```
PRAGMA restrict_references (Check_View, WNDS, TRUST);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction @MuhammadMuzzam.  The problem is `user_views` has some references which apparently violate Pragma in Oracle 12.

Seems to be an known issue:

https://community.oracle.com/thread/3650610?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Then use just: `PRAGMA restrict_references (Check_View, WNDS, TRUST);` and the body won't be checked during compilation.

Comment: I'll look into that @kordirko. Thanks.